# Rows in Kivy RecycleView repeating

Tags: python, kivy, recycle

I'm using Kivy RecycleView with a Row class to create an editable table of values.  The problem is that when I type an entry in one line, this value also appears in other lines further down in the table.  In the debugger, editing a row shows correctly the RecycleView.data updated for only that row which I typed in and not the other rows where they appeared so there seems to be a disconnect between the UI and the underlying data.  Can't understand what I might be missing or misunderstanding with this approach.  Please help.  Thank you!

I've included a [link](https://youtu.be/yjeXPnZNJfs) to a video of the behavior of the below code so hopefully it is self explanatory.  This doesn't happen when the initial rows are populated with unique values.

In the video, the application has three buttons.  The left button populates random unique values for the rows.  With these rows populated with unique values, editing them doesn't cause before mentioned problem and behaves expectedly. The middle and right buttons populate the rows with a repeated "None" text and blanks, respectively. When populating the rows with this type of data, editing any of these rows will cause the value to appear repeatedly further down when scrolling. I'm using Kivy 1.10.0 and Python 3.6.2 on OSX.

```
# based on code from https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/examples/widgets/recycleview/basic_data.py

from random import sample
from string import ascii_lowercase

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior

kv = """
<Row@BoxLayout>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    value: ''
    TextInput:
        multiline: False
        text: root.value
        on_text_validate: root.update(args[0].text)

<Test>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    rv: rv
    orientation: 'vertical'
    GridLayout:
        cols: 3
        rows: 1
        size_hint_y: None
        height: dp(108)
        padding: dp(8)
        spacing: dp(16)
        Button:
            text: 'Populate with text'
            on_press: root.populate_with_text()
        Button:
            text: 'Populate with same text'
            on_press: root.populate_with_same_text()
        Button:
            text: 'Populate with blanks'
            on_press: root.populate_with_blanks()
    RecycleView:
        id: rv
        scroll_type: ['bars', 'content']
        scroll_wheel_distance: dp(114)
        bar_width: dp(10)
        viewclass: 'Row'
        RecycleBoxLayout:
            default_size: None, dp(56)
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            orientation: 'vertical'
            spacing: dp(2)
"""


class Row(RecycleDataViewBehavior, BoxLayout):
    def update(self, text):
        self.parent.parent.data[self.index]['value'] = text
        self.parent.parent.refresh_from_data()

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        self.index = index
        return super(Row, self).refresh_view_attrs(rv, index, data)


class Test(BoxLayout):

    def populate_with_text(self):
        self.rv.data = [{'value': ''.join(sample(ascii_lowercase, 6)), 'index': x}
                        for x in range(50)]
        self.rv.refresh_from_data()

    def populate_with_same_text(self):
        self.rv.data = [{'value': 'None', 'index': x}
                        for x in range(50)]
        self.rv.refresh_from_data()

    def populate_with_blanks(self):
        self.rv.data = [{'value': '', 'index': x}
                        for x in range(50)]
        self.rv.refresh_from_data()


Builder.load_string(kv)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had a very similar problem, maybe you already solved it your way but maybe I help someone else.

Maybe you have noticed there are some issues related to this problem in Kivy github site too, but until now without solution.

Until now, all I have concluded is that is a bug with recycleview in kivy.

I haven't found the real solution but a personal workaround, in fact not even a 100% workaround, but it has worked this way for me.

It's a little bit embarrassment for me to post this type of workaround, but a lot of hours working in a simple problem like this makes you accept some "alternative" code to go forward.

So, to illustrate, I put in your code a focus event in kv file inside class Row@BoxLayout to refresh the visual bug problem, so the final kv file class stays like this:

```
<Row@BoxLayout>:
canvas.before:
    Color:
        rgba: 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1
    Rectangle:
        size: self.size
        pos: self.pos
value: ''
TextInput:
    multiline: False
    text: root.value
    on_text_validate: root.update(args[0].text)
    on_focus: self.text = root.value ## new line bug workaround
```

This extra line of code "corrects" the bug after it happen due the actual list is not affected by the bug, just the screen change, so the focus event refresh the value with the correct text.

The problem with this approach is if you start to change the text in InputText and simultaneously scroll the list, the problem will happen because the validate event will be executed in the wrong row, but if you just change the text and press Enter no problem.

I hope it help somebody.